# Laravel API request to a cloud model AI

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, request

I've been working on a in a route of validation for the user in Laravel API to connect to a NLP model in Google Cloud. Making the request go to the API them the API makes a request to a model in Google Cloud. After the prediction is given I pass back to the user.

The problem seems that it takes a certain almost of time to receive a answer from the model so I end up answering a empty JSON to the user.

I wish to ask what is better way to proceed in this situation.

```
public function request_To_The_Model(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();
        $response = Http::post(URL, [
            $data['sentence']
        ]);
        $body = $response->json();
        return response()->json($body);
    }
```

Comment: did you take a look a [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/long-operations) on how to handle long running operations? You could poll the status of the operation and when it's ready show it to the user

Comment: @Edgardo Thanks I gonna try to follow this guide